# Web service call

Tags: android, service

in my application I'm calling web service for creating lakes.for that user enters the lake name in edit text and i'm sending that entered name to web service.

now when I'm entering string with space the web service could not call successfully.it shows an exception that illegal char at (the space which I've give in edit text).
i"m not able to find solution for this since i want to send name with space in it.

any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: please post some code so we can fix.

Comment: @Umair....private void onCreateHotSopt() {

final EditText lake=(EditTextviewHotSpot.findViewById(R.id.lakeNameEditText);

//onclick of button

lakeName=lake.getText().toString().trim();

this lake name i wnt to pass to web service 
if lake name contains spaces e.g "test lake" give me exception of illegal char at index 5(which is space)

Comment: U need to eliminate empty space in you String values that all Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before adding lakeName to the webservice url, do this

```
final String encodedLakeName = URLEncoder.encode(lakeName, "UTF-8");
```

Now use this encodedLakeName.